# xcodebuild arguments ignored when using archive

Tags: continuous-integration, xcode4.2, archive, xcodebuild, organizer

My name is Luca and I am currently working on iOS continuous integration to build apps in xcode for distribution (Ad Hoc and App Store) using shell-scripting.

So far I achieved good results with IPA files. My problem comes for distribution in App Store. To build a .app from script (passing some arguments) I do:

```
xcodebuild -scheme myScheme -configuration myConfiguration PRODUCT_NAME=myProductName TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=myTargetedDeviceFamily .... etc
```

Since with XCode 4.2, apps submission is done using the XCode Organizer Window I must be able also to archive my executable.

Therefore I modify the previous command line as follow:

```
xcodebuild -scheme myScheme -configuration myConfiguration PRODUCT_NAME=myProductName TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY=myTargetedDeviceFamily .... etc      **archive**
```

Unfortunately after I do so, it seems that the 'archive' argument force xcodebuild to ignore the other ones (PRODUCT_NAME, TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY, ....) and my output is built using the XCode predefined build settings.

I want to be able to pass the arguments with xcodebuild and be effective, but the 'archive' action seems to prevent this.

I am going nuts, please help :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The *archive* action for xcodebuild seems to have a bug in Xcode 4.2. Normally overrides for the project configuration can be specified as either command-line parameters or via the `-xcconfig` parameter.

Although the *build* action honors them, *archive* does not. (Presumably this is because archive is a meta-action that invokes build internally, but doesn't pass-through the options to the internal invocation.) There is an OpenRadar [bug](http://www.openradar.me/10319577) that describes this issue, so presumably it's been reported to Apple.

Finally, note that if you're going to use the *archive* action from a script then you can't rely on the exit code from xcodebuild. The archive action always yields an exit code of 0 (success, by convention). To detect build failure you need to scrape the output.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into this same issue. My current work-around is basically to delete the other configurations so archive is forced to use the one you want. Not really a solution that can be done via command-line, hopefully Apple will fix this glaring issue.

Answer (score -1):

this may be too late for the original poster, but may help others. for my build process, i use xcodebuild to with first clean and then build, then i use xcrun to create the archive:

```
 /usr/bin/xcrun -sdk iphoneos PackageApplication -v "build/<Path_to_build_dir>/<App_Name>.app" -o "<Path_to_archive_output>.ipa" --sign "<signing identity>" --embed "<path to provision profile>.mobileprovision"
```

with this command, i can create an archive for the app store, or even upload an ad-hoc build to TestFlight like this:

```
curl http://testflightapp.com/api/builds.json \
    -F file="<path to archive>" \
    -F api_token='<api token>' \
    -F team_token='<team token>' \
    -F notes='Automated build'  \
    -F notify=True \
    -F distribution_lists='me'
```

this works as of xcode 6.1