# xcodebuild command line ignoring GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcodebuild, xcode4.3

I'm trying to launch xcodebuild with different preprocessing macros.

I've tried :

```
xcodebuild -scheme myscheme \
           -configuration "Archive" \
           -sdk "iphoneos5.1" 
           archive \
           CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=../build \
           GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS=ADHOC
```

but i got a compilation error due to the fact the preprocessor was not used:

I couldn't see it with the -D flag of the compilation command

But it is displayed at the beginning of the script

```
Build settings from command line:
        CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ../build
        GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = ADHOC
        SDKROOT = iphoneos5.1
```

The code at the origin of the compilation error is:

```
#ifdef ADHOC
NSUInteger toto = 0;
#endif
```

but i get a `use of undeclared identifier` error for `toto`

ps : if i do define Preprocessor Macros in Xcode, then these values are used, mine are overridden, and archiving is done. But I do want to make several builds based on different preprocessor definitions (which sounds a better idea than creating new build configurations or schemes to me)

Comment: It seems to be working for me.  Can you provide a sample project that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: By the way, I disagree that preprocessor definitions are the best approach here.  They are inherently more limited than the alternatives.  Have you considered using one schema, one configuration, but multiple targets?

Comment: i already experienced multiple targets in a project and hated it: too many checkboxes to check any time you include new code to a project. But maybe it would make sense here.

Comment: what version of Xcode are you using? (mine is 4.3.1 - Build version 4E1019). i'll try to create a small project to demonstrate the problem soon...

Comment: I'm using the same version of Xcode as you.

Comment: Have you been able to resolve this issue yet? I have the same problem on Xcode 4.3.2 while trying to automate the expiration of an in-house build (build script passes output of the `date` command as a macro that should be acted upon).

Comment: There is another, older question detailing the exact same phenomenon: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8562031/xcodebuild-arguments-ignored-when-using-archive In addition, the one answer to that question links to a [bug on OpenRadar](http://www.openradar.me/10319577) which I’d encourage you to duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

I have to use double quote and remove the $value. 
I had,

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$value ${e}',
```

which did not work, but

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS="${e}"
```

works.

Where, e is variable inside a loop,

```
environments=("TEST1" "TEST2" "TEST3" "TEST4" "TEST5" "PROD")
for e in "${environments[@]}"
   do
....... commands
   done
```

If I use

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$value ${e}'
```

Then I have to use like,

```
GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS='$value ADHOC=1'
```

This worked in one of build script.